# Need help regarding jComboBox and jTable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

So i have this jTable on my frame and a jComboBox. Inside my jComboBox is the list of phones. What i want to do is to have the jTable get the database of a specific product inside the jComboBox. Suppose i pick the Samsung S7 in the jComboBox. When i click the "Details" jButton the jTable will show the Data of Samsung S7(Model, Price, Stock, etc.). How do i do this? Here is my code:

```
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectephone","root","");
        String sql= "select * from samsung";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs= pst.executeQuery();
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to add");
    }
}
```

But this code just make my jTable show all of my data inside my database table. Any ideas?

Comment: Java Swing is supported on Android?

Comment: Lol, im sorry. I didnt see that tag. Wait, i'll edit it.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for examples of how to write a listener to get the selected item in the combo box and do processing on that value.

Answer (score 3):

When the details button is clicked

1. get the current selected phone from the `JComboBox` (given as phone name or internal id into your database table or whatever)
2. and then use this value to limit your search.

For example

```
String phoneName = ... // current selected in the  the combobox
String sql= "select * from samsung where name = ?";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, phoneName); 
ResultSet rs= pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Do i have to do this in every item on my list? I have 15 items inside my combobox

Comment: it should work as generic solution - as long as every item in the combobox gives you a column value which you can use to filter the search

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll try it out. One more thing. The "String phoneName" is this the variable name of the combobox or the item? If its the item then should i also declare a string for the rest of my items?

Comment: this should represent the selected item in the combobox, i.e. `phonesComboBox.getSelectedItem()`. If it is a string, or some other type depends on how you filled the combobox. My code is just an example how it could look like.

Comment: I still got error. Please tell me what i did wrong:

  String jComboBox1 = 
            String sql= "select * from samsung where name=?";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, jComboBox1);
            ResultSet rs= pst.executeQuery();
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

Comment: Don't post code as a comment. Edit your question with the code. I would guess the problem with your code is that you use the "jComboBox1" as the parameter for the where clause. Well you can't do that you need to use: `comboBox.setSelectedItem().toString()`. Did you even use a System.out.println(...) statement to see what the value was that you tried to do the where on????? This is basic debugging which you need to learn instead of asking the same question 3 or 4 times.